# Best way to store widgets, XTHML snippets and containers in PHP

Tags: php, templates, optimization

I have a a few XHTML widgets and containers that have static or mostly static content. When I say mostly static, I mean a widget which is using one or more variables passed to it from a DB or a configuration. These are all used in more than one frontend page. Currently, I have stored them as PHP functions that return a XHTML string, and these functions are stored in a singular "functions" file that is "included" on every page. Where applicable, I either pass these functions configuration values or do some DB calls from within.

Is there another better way to store these in PHP code? Or is what I am doing pretty standard?

(I am not using Smarty or another template system and I'd rather not add another layer of abstraction.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's pretty standard, most you can do is separate them into files for each and then have a "includes" files that includes each one of them.

This way you would only have to load what you need per script / page.

Answer (score 0):

> (I am not using Smarty or another template system and I'd rather not add another layer of abstraction.)

I know this isnt what you want but this is exacly what id do. I wouldnt necessarily use a template engine with its wone grammar but i would use php and make seperate snippet templates containing the structural markup and then pass in what i need for example:

```
function get_partial($path, $args = array())
{
   ob_start();
   include($path);
   return ob_get_clean();
}

function include_partial($path, $args = array())
{
   echo get_partial($path, $args);
}
```

Then in your template:

```
<div class="<?php echo $args['classname']?>">
  <h4><?php echo $args['title'] ?></h4>
  <?php echo $args['content'] ?>
</div>
```